# How do I upload multiple files using FileUploader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

How to go about uploading Multiple files(i have multiple files inside a folder) using file uploader by selecting target folder once in asp.net.if not using file uploader is there any other control for uploading file in asp.net?

Comment: From the looks of the FileControl documentation is designed to accept a single File (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) . Did you have a look at other approach such as - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-multiple-file-uploads-in-aspnet-2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options to upload multiple files:

1. You can use a jQuery plugin, as described [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317).
2. You can use as many FileUpload controls as needed, as described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-multiple-file-uploads-in-aspnet-2) (videotutorial) and [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=68).

But none that I can think of will allow you to select and entire "folder".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good explanation of why this is not possible with standard .net controls on [Velocity Reviews](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t671288-can-we-recursively-upload-files-using-standard-asp-net.html).

Here's more info on using Flash or Silverlight on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542415/upload-a-folder-in-asp-net-of-flash-or-silverlight). In summary, you *can* use something that allows multiple files to be uploaded (that the user manually selects) but you can't select a folder and have it upload each item in it, presumably because this breaks a law of the security gods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Radupload for multiple file upload.