# Embed WinForms in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, web

I need to make an upload application. ASP.NET already has an UploadFile control. But there is one more requirement: to be able to select a folder and to upload all his content. So I need to create an FolderBrowse control to be able to select a folder. Becase the SelectFile dialog that is included in UploadFile control looks so professional the DirectoryBrowse should look the same. I google it and found 2 solution: 1. to create in windows form a control that opena a file and opens a folder and gives the consumer the selected path.... and 2. it was something with using interop to be able to use a .net folderBrowse control ....not very clear to me this one that's why I tried to create an windows forms control and embed it in web site. The problem is:

1.

In designer I got an text over the control : The control type was not specified or the specified type could not be found.

in browser I see a little rectangle where the control should be.

If I add type = application then in browser I see nothing at all.

In win forms control I set for the user control:
  [ComVisible(true)]

Can someone give me a clue please? what I am doing wrong? Or maybe another solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload a folder in ASP.NET of Flash or Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542415/upload-a-folder-in-asp-net-of-flash-or-silverlight)

Comment: I saw the post...I see no answer there to my solution. To embed the FolderBrowse in ASP.NET.